# How to show console messages inside of import class?

Tags: laravel

In my console command I call ImportQuizApiData method :

```
use App\Library\ImportQuizApiData;
...
class ImportQuizApiDataCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'app:import-quiz-api-data-command  {categoryName?}';

    public function handle()
    {
        ...
        $importQuizApiData = new ImportQuizApiData();
        $importQuizApiData->setParentCommand($this);
        $importResult = $importQuizApiData->import();
        ...
```

Inside of import method of ImportQuizApiData object I show current process in console :

```
class ImportQuizApiData
{
    protected ImportQuizApiDataCommand $parentCommand;
    ...
    public function setParentCommand(ImportQuizApiDataCommand $value): self
    {
        $this->parentCommand = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function import(): bool
    {
        ...
        $currentRow = 0;
        foreach ($this->data) {
            ...
            $currentRow++;
            $this->parentCommand->info($currentRow . ' / ' . count($this->data) . ' - ' . (100 / count($this->data) * $currentRow) . '% ');
        } // foreach ($sourceQuizzesArray as $quiz) {  // Loop all quizzes
```

I dislike a way as I passed $parentCommand var into ImportQuizApiData object, but how can I do it in a better way ?
I know how to use events / listeners - but looks like it is not helpfull here...

Comment: Why cant you just remove `$importQuizApiData->setParentCommand($this);` then just  run `$importResult = $importQuizApiData->import();`?

Comment: Without `$importQuizApiData->setParentCommand($this)` I have no reference to parent console command inside of $importQuizApiData onject

Comment: What are you trying to reference? The value of `categoryName`? The command itself?

Comment: I can see `$this->parentCommand->info`, Am I correct to assume you wish to use the methods of parent inside api class?

Comment: If so, then I would suggest create a separate helper class instead and use it in both parent and api class

Comment: @Mr. Kenneth, yes. Not sure that I understand about separate helper class. Please detalize your idea

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use both methods from parent and child class, I would suggest to use helper class.

**ImportQuizHelper**

```
namespace {namespace path here}
...
class ImportQuizHelper {

    public function info() {

    }
    ... 
    // move all methods here
    // you may add more methods here that can be used on both api and command
}
```

**ImportQuizApiData**

```
...
use {namespace path here}\ImportQuizHelper;
use App\Library\ImportQuizApiData;
class ImportQuizApiDataCommand extends Command
{
    private $helper;
    public __construct(ImportQuizHelper $helper) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    protected $signature = 'app:import-quiz-api-data-command  {categoryName?}';

    public function handle()
    {
        ...
        $importQuizApiData = new ImportQuizApiData($this->helper); // pass helper here
        $importResult = $importQuizApiData->import();
        ...

        $this->helper->info(); // use info from helper

    }
}
```

**ImportQuizApiData**

```
...
class ImportQuizApiData
{
    private $helper;
    public __construct(ImportQuizHelper $helper) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function import()
    {
        ... // do your imports
        $this->helper->info(); // use info from helper
    }
}
```

There might be bugs or typo here since I just wrote it on the fly so just edit if needed.

Comment: substitute `{namespace path here}` with your actual namespace where you save your helper class

Comment: ,1)  in my code `info(` method belongs to  Command class. ( link https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#writing-output ). I do not definethis method, like in your code. 2) Maybe there is a way to use `info(` method  of facade static method, without refereing it as `$this->`

Comment: Oh I see. I was thinking custom methods, not methods from commands, Disregarding my code above, have you tried `self::parent()->info()` in your api?

Comment: I tried to use `self::parent()->info(` - but got error : `Call to undefined method App\Library\ImportQuizApiData::parent()`

        I checked https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-parent-class.php  docs,
        but code `get_parent_class($this)` returns false, as next I got error : `Call to a member function info() on bool`

Comment: of  so not `self::parent()->info()` but `self::nfo()`

Comment: since self is pointing to `ImportQuizApiData` so we remove `parent()`

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is :

-have ImportQuizApiData() injected as a dependency

-remove the setter (setParentCommand($this)) and have the import to do that (optional)

```
use App\Library\ImportQuizApiData;
...
class ImportQuizApiDataCommand extends Command
{
  protected $signature = 'app:import-quiz-api-data-command  {categoryName?}';

  public function handle(ImportQuizApiData $importQuizApiData)
  {
    ...
    $importResult = $importQuizApiData->import($this);
    ...
  }
}


class ImportQuizApiData
{

  protected ImportQuizApiDataCommand $parentCommand;
  ...


  public function import($parentCommand): bool
  {
    //if(! $this->parentCommand){//optional
    //  $this->parentCommand = $parentCommand;
    //}
    ...
    $currentRow = 0;
    foreach ($this->data) {
        ...
        $currentRow++;
        $parentCommand->info($currentRow . ' / ' . count($this->data) . ' - ' . (100 / count($this->data) * $currentRow) . '% ');
        //$this->parentCommand->info($currentRow . ' / ' . count($this->data) . ' - ' . (100 / count($this->data) * $currentRow) . '% ');
    } // foreach ($sourceQuizzesArray as $quiz) {  // Loop all quizzes
```

Comment: and in this case `class ImportQuizApiData` would have a reference to `class ImportQuizApiDataCommand` anyway? That is just what I try to avoid... But not sure is it possible...

Comment: sure you can avoid i guess... just don t set the parent command, see the edit.